# Testar a interação com o html e JavaScript utilizando o Jasmine é errado?

Tags: javascript, testes-de-unidade, jasmine

O código em JavaScript possui algumas interações com o html como esse exemplo:

```
function retornaListaDeItens(argument) {
  return document.getElementsByClassName(argument);
}
```

Utilizo o retorno dessa função para a realização de operações no JavaScript, realizando os teste de unidade utilizando o Jasmine acabei me deparando com o seguinte cenário de dúvidas:

1. É errado realizar o teste dessa função?
2. É possível simular o meu html para realizar testes que fazem interações com ele?

A estrutura do teste utiliza o próprio arquivo *SpecRunner.html* do Jasmine e não tem contato com o html onde possui a lista de itens a ser retornada nesse exemplo, isso acaba dificultando os testes de unidade.

A estrutura esta mais ou menos assim:

```
app
  lib
  --bootstrap
  --jasmine
  src
  --css
  --js
    --teste.js
  test
  --testeSpec.js
  index.html
```

A ideia de teste é assim:

```
  it("retorno de lista de itens não deve ser vazio", function() {
    var item = "item";
    var list = retornaListaDeItens(item);
    console.log(list.length);
    expect(list).not.toBeLessThan(0);
  });
```

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?

Comment: Olá @durtto, bem estudei sobre boas práticas de programação em JavaScript junto com boas praticas de testes e acabei descobrindo que muito do que estava fazendo não estava seguindo essas boas práticas, um exemplo disso era misturar o comportamento de buscar na tela junto com algumas regras, bem resumindo separei meu js que faz a comunicação com a tela e meu js que faz realmente a regra de negócio e realizei os testes somente no que realiza as regras de negócio.

Comment: Que bom Emanoel. Fico feliz que você estude como gente grande. Isso ajuda a comunidade. Tente fazer o seguinte, se você encontrou a resposta, escreva ela aqui e não deixe a pergunta sem resposta, pois assim você ajuda pessoas que estejam na mesma situação. A Comunidade agradece.

Comment: Olá @durtto, sim pretendo fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Ví que resolveu o problema e fico feliz por isso, mas ainda sim a necessidade de fazer testes reais na aplicação existe em muitos casos.

Caso você queira testar uma aplicação como um usuário (simular ações no HTML e esperar os retornos para verificar se estão corretos) você pode usar alguma lib para auxiliar no que chamamos de testes e2e (end to end).

Esses testes são mais trabalhosos e mais lentos, porém buscam emular exatamente as ações de um usuário dentro do sistema.

Aconselho pesquisar e ler sobre: [SeleniumHQ](http://seleniumhq.org), [PhantomJS](http://PhantomJS), [WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io/) e [Chimp](https://chimp.readme.io).

Confesso que meu conhecimento com esse tipo de testes é bem raso, mas estou estudando e me aprofundando a cada dia e já posso lhe afirmar que para grandes sistemas são muito úteis.

Bons estudos!

---

EDIT:

Eu não faço meus testes com jasmine, mas sim com [MochaJS](https://mochajs.org/), aconselho você dar uma olhada também.